# Flat стиль бордюра у GroupBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

Подскажите как убрать 3D эффект бордюра у `GroupBox` и сделать его `Flat` стилем. Сейчас если я выбираю `BorderThickness` равный 1, то только с левой стороны он нужного цвета. С остальных он промежуточного цвета между фоном и цветом бордюра.

Код:

```
<!-- Account settings -->
<GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="Account Properties" Height="121" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="232" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckboxStyle}" Content=" Allow auto sign in." Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,8,0,0" Name="autoLoginCheckBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Unchecked="autoLoginCheckBox_Changed" Checked="autoLoginCheckBox_Changed">
            <!--<CheckBox.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="1" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
            </CheckBox.Effect>-->
        </CheckBox>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,37,0,0" Name="loginBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="loginBox_TextChanged" IsEnabled="True" />
        <PasswordBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,69,0,0" Name="passwordBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" PasswordChanged="passwordBox_PasswordChanged" />
        <Label Content="Password:" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,67,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Foreground="White">
            <!--<Label.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="1" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
            </Label.Effect>-->
        </Label>
        <Label Content="Login:" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,36,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Foreground="White">
            <!--<Label.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="1" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
            </Label.Effect>-->
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

Скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую Visual Studio 2010. В ней нет возможности скопировать шаблон элемента чтобы после, на его основе, сделать свой.

Comment: Вы забыли привести код стиля в вопросе

Comment: Извиняюсь. Код элемента добавил.

Comment: У вас какая ОС? Если вы хотите плоские контролы, просто возьмите библиотеку с темой Aero2

Comment: @АндрейNOP Все необходимые мне контролы я переписал. Точнее нашёл готовые стили, которые переписал под себя. А вот с GroupBox проблема. Как я понял - он составной. И в поиске нет близких для меня решений. Мне не нужен контрол зависящий от ОС и её темы. Именно из-за этого, в большей степени, я и ушёл в WPF. А Flat стиль только из-за того, что именно в нём граница представляется всего лишь линией.

Comment: Скрин что в вопросе на какой ОС сделан?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Windows 7 с темой Aero+ под Windows 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Использую Visual Studio 2010. В ней нет возможности скопировать шаблон
>   элемента чтобы после, на его основе, сделать свой.

Если проблема только в этом, то вы "сами себе злобный Буратино".

Вот вам стандартный стиль с Windows 10, вроде плоский, попробуйте:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BorderGapMaskConverter x:Key="BorderGapMaskConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="GroupBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D5DFE5"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                            <Border.OpacityMask>
                                <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="7" Converter="{StaticResource BorderGapMaskConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="Header" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Border.OpacityMask>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Header" Grid.Column="1" Padding="3,1,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это мне и нужно было. Всё получилось как я и хотел. [Скрин](http://joxi.ru/J2b9KqwtXkPEpm) прилагаю. К сожалению, я изучаю C# по книжке. И пока не наберусь опыта не сменю версию VS. К тому же она у меня настроена под меня, а как и где я уже не помню. Да и настраивать SVN плагин придётся заново. А так да, я местами "злобный буратино". Каюсь.